# Group by 30min interval SOQL

Tags: soql, query, roll-up-summary, group-by

I have below SOQL which runs fine to retrieve all hourly results for a given day (15-Aug in below example). I now need to break it down by 30minutes interval.Is that possible using a single SOQL statement in Salesforce?

```
SELECT HOUR_IN_DAY(convertTimezone(CreatedDate)) Time, count(id) OpportunityCount
FROM Opportunity
where CreatedDate > 2022-08-14T23:59:00.204+05:30 and CreatedDate < 2022-08-16T00:30:00.204+05:30 and RecordType.Name = 'Support' 
GROUP BY rollup(HOUR_IN_DAY(convertTimezone(CreatedDate)))
order by HOUR_IN_DAY(convertTimezone(CreatedDate))
```

if not then can someone help me with an anonymous block that I can run.My apex knowledge is very limited

Comment: Use a Text formula field on the object that calculates the half hour bucket for a given record's createdDate; then group on that formula field; formula values would be `0000-0029`,`0030-0059`, ...

Comment: @cropredy Thanks.I have that approach as backup :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Text formula field on the object that calculates the half hour bucket for a given record's `CreatedDate`. Formula values would be 0000-0029,0030-0059, ...

```
IF (HOUR(CreatedDate) = 0 && MINUTE(CreatedDate) < 30, '0000-0029',
IF (HOUR(CreatedDate) = 0 && MINUTE(CreatedDate) >= 30, '0030-0059',
...
```

there are cleverer ways to generate these 48 strings using fewer lines but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.

Then group on that formula field in your Aggregate query

**References**

[Example Date and Time formulas](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.usefulFormulaFields.meta/usefulFormulaFields/formula_examples_dates.htm)

[Trailhead on Date and Times formulas](https://trailblazer.me/setup/secur/RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage.apexp?source=CAAAAYMUsAUfMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwAAAA7kPLAFQs8qW9z4TJJ9jaBmqQMqPmGbrpdngfowmgNW2Nsb8E44sLc5wynW_lFFUXnOav3g2VxYoVLV7aU35OAIGISwnYM2J1i1_B7CETSU-KDLLpDcMAbI9WexeCWPbgCAOwS6l_4bVzEIpaRuIpnEccCUkIMbMt5Cockoyprgn-Nybe19SEBbnfFe1fY00rSSEVNuIXojtgp9xPRC0lXTrJwPgguUfSH7R3v9XRoyN4lS7cDQWWKdciwTzdX8hTeUBUqxLr0Oz90eUm7IDP82wHrpr6mrVTb5kP2wie6Jocid_qv3EjdOjlRtaL04zZ1x3g_mZpM75EaleZL8HQ8WVAtq5ocPHOdv6vv65k5DPydhdT0tdICZRUiQ1wrW0SaBpIvt0rczgB_YiNUTUd1mvUj8OLLgxXOfpiXr1WizpqqJ8W5cvoo73IMdfHi4XVM8GyvvGtSXv59R9RXcraAudFTHwvZCJzxzC0-8hUCGmGDUe31Qyg1LNNALUIWLPtAz7L0ywl17tTckL6KpQt8siFeFcQqsczHfCU8LtrmuAYZn5iaHUtdGGTNRpabUoNj_nUJwURARZEulFkKv5nmgHtv-SOhTb1UdhWP3vdLf3mY1EaQfBnnWK58Rdp0f2rB832VxaSWjdp3Ck8wg20zg0YIbrUc02QFciI8f_IDsoYGaPzrpCHVwJOemvYvj9nqPf-kbhPnwXUk2n_pbHpkDT8_YWD-BSzCqcpfPoeJAT1_VWOxXUbhq95e0APAt6m2w%3D%3D&display=page)

Answer (score -3):

i have updated the query it will give aggrrgrate result of records that are created within 30 min of interval:-

```
SELECT HOUR_IN_DAY(convertTimezone(CreatedDate)) Time, count(id) OpportunityCount FROM Opportunity where CreatedDate <:System.now()  and CreatedDate >:System.now().addminutes(-30) GROUP BY rollup(HOUR_IN_DAY(convertTimezone(CreatedDate))) order by HOUR_IN_DAY(convertTimezone(CreatedDate));
```

in place of System.now user can put any specific date also.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question being asked. The question is not "get records created within the past 30 minutes", it is "group records by creation date in intervals of 30 minutes". Two records created at 10:45 and 10:50 would be in the same 30-minute interval. Two records created at 10:15 and 10:50 would be in separate (and adjacent) 30-minute intervals.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: This still doesn't answer the question being asked.